# geb.error.PageInstanceNotInitializedException

Tags: grails, groovy, cucumber, geb

I am new in using Geb and Cucumber for grails and I am following this tutorial https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/wiki/Testing-Grails-with-Cucumber-and-Geb

Everything has been fine up until I made a Page class and used it in my step definition. I ran the test and this error showed up.

```
Error running forked test-app: Instance of page class pages.ListPage has not 
been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), 
Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it. (NOTE: Stack trace has been 
filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
geb.error.PageInstanceNotInitializedException: Instance of page class 
pages.ListPage has not been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), 
Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
```

I just copied everything in the tutorial and I double checked my codes for typos so I don't know what I did wrong.

this is my ListPage.groovy

```
package pages

import geb.Page

class ListPage extends Page{
    static  url = "book/list"

    static at = {
        title ==~/Book List/
    }

    static content = {

    }
}
```

my Book_steps.groovy

```
import static cucumber.api.groovy.EN.*
import pages.ListPage
import geb.Browser


Given (~'^I open the book tracker$') { ->
// Since it said that it has not been initialized, i tried this 
//    def listpage = new ListPage() 
//    to listpage
//    at listpage

    to ListPage
    at ListPage
}

When (~'^I add "([^"]*)"$') { String bookTitle ->
   assert false
}

Then (~'^I see "([^"]*)"s details$') { String bookTitle ->
    assert false
}
```

my env.groovy

```
import geb.binding.BindingUpdater
import geb.Browser

import static cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks.*

Before () {
    bindingUpdater = new BindingUpdater (binding, new Browser ())
    bindingUpdater.initialize ()
}

After () {
    bindingUpdater.remove ()
}
```

BuildConfig.groovy

```
def seleniumVersion = "2.47.1"  
dependencies {
    test ("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion")
    test ("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion")
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.12.0"
}

plugins {
    test ":cucumber:1.2.0"
    test ":geb:0.12.0"
}
```

EDIT: verbose stack trace error

```
Fatal error running tests: Instance of page class pages.ListPage has not been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
geb.error.PageInstanceNotInitializedException: Instance of page class       pages.ListPage has not been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:244)
    at geb.Page.uninitializedException(Page.groovy:502)
    at pages.ListPage.uninitializedException(ListPage.groovy)
    at geb.Initializable$uninitializedException.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at geb.content.UninitializedPageContentSupport.getContent(UninitializedPageContentSupport.groovy:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:163)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport.propertyMissing(PageContentSupport.groovy:52)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport$propertyMissing.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at geb.Page.propertyMissing(Page.groovy:99)
    at pages.ListPage.propertyMissing(ListPage.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2721)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.setProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1181)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3746)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setPropertySafe(InvokerHelper.java:484)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:457)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:704)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:684)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.parse(GroovyBackend.java:115)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.loadGlue(GroovyBackend.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:268)
    at grails.plugin.cucumber.CucumberTestType.prepareCucumber(CucumberTestType.groovy:73)
    at grails.plugin.cucumber.CucumberTestType.doPrepare(CucumberTestType.groovy:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.support.GrailsTestTypeSupport.prepare(GrailsTestTypeSupport.groovy:98)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:404)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.processTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$_runAllTests_closure7.doCall(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:314)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:5223)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$163.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:300)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$runAllTests$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.runInstance(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.run(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.main(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:75)
Error |
Fatal error running tests: Instance of page class pages.ListPage has not   been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
.Tests FAILED
|
 - view reports in C:\Users\Patrick\IdeaProjects\cucumberprac\target\test-   reports
Error |
Error running forked test-app: Instance of page class pages.ListPage has not   been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
geb.error.PageInstanceNotInitializedException: Instance of page class pages.ListPage has not been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:244)
    at geb.Page.uninitializedException(Page.groovy:502)
    at pages.ListPage.uninitializedException(ListPage.groovy)
    at geb.Initializable$uninitializedException.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at geb.content.UninitializedPageContentSupport.getContent(UninitializedPageContentSupport.groovy:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:163)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport.propertyMissing(PageContentSupport.groovy:52)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport$propertyMissing.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at geb.Page.propertyMissing(Page.groovy:99)
    at pages.ListPage.propertyMissing(ListPage.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2721)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.setProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1181)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3746)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setPropertySafe(InvokerHelper.java:484)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:457)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:704)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:684)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.parse(GroovyBackend.java:115)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.loadGlue(GroovyBackend.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:268)
    at grails.plugin.cucumber.CucumberTestType.prepareCucumber(CucumberTestType.groovy:73)
    at grails.plugin.cucumber.CucumberTestType.doPrepare(CucumberTestType.groovy:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.support.GrailsTestTypeSupport.prepare(GrailsTestTypeSupport.groovy:98)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:404)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.processTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$_runAllTests_closure7.doCall(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:314)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:5223)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$163.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:300)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$runAllTests$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.runInstance(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.run(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.main(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:75)
Error |
Error running forked test-app: Instance of page class pages.ListPage has not been initialized. Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
```

Comment: Can you please paste the whole stacktrace (run it with `--verbose` and paste everything that comes out)? I can't see anything wrong with your code but the stacktrace might hold a clue.

Comment: i edited my post, it's there :)

Comment: Did you by any chance put your page class under `test/cucumber/steps` directory?

Comment: No i didn't. Should it be there? Mine is at it's own folder `test/functional/pages` just like in the tutorial. But i didn't configure my cucumber to have a separate folder. All of them are in the `test/functiona`l 
folder

Comment: Yes, it should go into `test/functional/pages` and not `test/cucumber/steps` so you have it in the right place. What about your steps? Are they in `test/cucumber/steps`? I'm asking because if I'm reading the stacktrace right then the error is thrown when loading the steps and not when executing them which I did not expect. Any chance you could put your project or an extract of it exposing the issue on github so that I can have a look? If you do so then please let me know which Grails version you're using so that I use the right one when investigating.

Comment: My steps are in `test/functional/steps` folder. I didn't configure my cucumber to have it's own folder. Could that be a possible reason? 
I don't know if this helps but if I remove all the code related to the page class and put `go http://localhost:8090/cucumberprac/book/index` in my steps, it actually executes them and firefox opens to the link. 
Anyway here is the link to the repo on github `https://github.com/uLan08/geb-cucumber-practice`. I am using grails version 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you cannot put your cucumber code and page classes inside of `test/functional` because it causes cucumber to treat your page classes as step definitions and when it tries to load them it fails with the exception you are seeing.

When I added `grails-app/conf/CucumberConfig.groovy` file with contents as per the tutorial you linked to:

```
cucumber {
    features = ["test/cucumber"]
    glue = features
}
```

and moved `test/functional/NewBook.feature`, `test/functional/support` and `test/functional/steps` into `test/cucumber` I was able to run your tests - the example is still failing because there is no `list` action in `BookController` but that's a completely different problem.

Looks like following the tutorial to the letter would have saved you some head scratching. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks! I could have made a lot of progress if I did. xD