# Upload image in grails using REST and save name of the image

Tags: json, api, rest, grails

I am trying to upload image with grails using REST in my local Machine.
This is the controller

```
class FileimgController {

def upload() {
    def image = request.getFile('myFile')
    image.transferTo(new File('/home/mehandihassan/workspace/imgfile/grails-app/assets/images/mehandi.'))
    response.sendError(200, 'Done')
}

def index() { }
}
```

Here the domain class

```
@Resource(uri = '/imageUpload', formats = ['json','xml'])
class Fileimg {
String imgName

static constraints = {

    imgName(nullable:true)
}
}
```

getting 
  Error: 500 internal server error

I am using HTTPRequester

any solution ?

can we upload image by using this code 
code reference
https://grails.org/single-page-documentation.html

I have done some changes in this code can we use this code for REST API
or 
should i use any plugin to upload image or any file ?

Comment: Paste your stacktrace error.

Comment: Hi @MichalSzulc I have done some changes in question can you please go through it if any confusion then comment please.

Comment: You didn't show your stacktrace log with details of an error. Moreover write which version of Grails are you using.

Comment: Grails 3.0.1 version

Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
 at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:110)

Comment: please paste your **verbose** stacktrace log; check how other people do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507964/geb-error-pageinstancenotinitializedexception